# Can't save xdotool output in a variable or a file

Tags: linux, bash, xdotool

I am simulating a keypress event that gives some text output on the terminal.

For ex -
command - "xdotool key d"
gives some string output on terminal -

But I cannot save it in the file.
What's the issue and how to do this?

`# xdotool key d > output.txt`